# How to identify SMD components?

Tags: integrated-circuit, surface-mount

I am trying to understand SMD components. Came accross ICs and seems like quite hard to hunderstand. Is there any general rule? Could someone help me to identify the ICs in the pics. One is marked as
"1H1H 788 A5DS" and the second is "DZAA XVFH". I searched those names, but couldn't find anything.[image]
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately SMD components aren't marked with identification as a prime goal. They sacrifice marking for small size. You'll sometimes get a date code, and sometimes a few cryptic characters which google might know about. The general idea is that you know what they are when you buy them, and you keep them in the marked container until you fit them.

Answer (score 2):

I think, the SMDs in the pictures are:

- "DZAA XVFH" : ISL80102/ISL80103 [datasheet](https://www.renesas.com/br/ja/www/doc/datasheet/isl80102-03.pdf)
- "1H1H 788 A5DS" : ISL80102/ISL80103 [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv755p.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-mousermode-df-pf-null-wwe&DCM=yes)

About, How I find the smd component? I usually try each group of the name plus "datasheet" and if I don't find anything, I may add some description word. For example:

- For the first one I just googled for: "DZAA datasheet"
- However, the second one was not that easy, I tried "1H1H datasheet", "788 datasheet",... Until I tried "1H1H datasheet IC".

The way to check that you were correct is mainly check the pinout, and the "marking" section in the datasheets. In the DZAA, for example, the pinout have double Vin and Vout pins, and in the image, they are soldered together, so I can be pretty sure, it is the correct datasheet.

O hope this have been helpful.